# How to use PowerShell Remove-Item to delete a directory with long name?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I am trying to remove a directory with numerous files with long file names. I am unable to do GUI based normal delete and I turned for a command based delete. But even so I am setting this error shown in image below. Can some one guide me?

[image]

Comment: See some answers here: [Delete directory regardless of 260 char limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392765/delete-directory-regardless-of-260-char-limit)

Comment: You can try to do something like this: `$Y = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network 
$Y.MapNetworkDrive( "Y:", "\\Hostname\C$\rcptttest\Foldername1\Foldername2\foldername3", "true", "domain\username", "password" )
Remove-Item Y:\Foldername4\Foldername5 -recurse -Force
$Y.RemoveNetworkDrive( "Y:" )`

Comment: I don't think I can access this over any other network.

Comment: @OlafReitz, no there are too many nested directories each with very long names. Hence I have even tried it from C: directory, even there I am unable to.